# Remove all elements from a dynamic map in clojure

Tags: clojure, maps, dynamic-mapping

I have a Dynamic Map

```
(def ^:dynamic all-elements-name-map {})
```

I have inserted many elements to this map in an iteration. In order to prepare for the next iteration i need to clear all the contents in this map.  Is there a inbuilt way to clear all the elements or do i need to dissoc each element from the map in a loop

Comment: How are you going about "inserting" many elements to your map?

Comment: Can't you just set it to an empty map? It sounds like you should use an atom here: `(def all-elements-name-map {})`, then to clear, you just do `(reset! all-elements-name-map {})`

Comment: Thanks Using atom Helped!